# Add a edit text to search for items in a ListView

Tags: android, list, listview, search

Hello i am new to android and i am trying to add a search field to search for items in a listview. I have tried a couple of ways including the TextWatcher but i am unable to get it working successfully

```
package com.example.permission;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ListView mListAppInfo;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // set layout for the main screen
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);

        // load list application
        mListAppInfo = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvApps);
        EditText search = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText01);

        mListAppInfo.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        // create new adapter
        AppInfoAdapter adapter = new AppInfoAdapter(this, Utilities.getSystemFilteredApplication(this), getPackageManager());

        // set adapter to list view  
        mListAppInfo.setAdapter(adapter);

        TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
               adapter.getFilter().filter(s); //Filter from my adapter
               adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //Update my view
            }

        };

        // implement event when an item on list view is selected
        mListAppInfo.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                // get the list adapter
                AppInfoAdapter appInfoAdapter = (AppInfoAdapter)parent.getAdapter();
                // get selected item on the list
                ApplicationInfo appInfo = (ApplicationInfo)appInfoAdapter.getItem(pos);
                // launch the selected application
                //Utilities.launchApp(parent.getContext(), getPackageManager(), appInfo.packageName);
                Utilities.getPermissions(parent.getContext(), getPackageManager(), appInfo.packageName);
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You have clicked on package: " + appInfo.packageName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }
}
```

EDIT: tried to implement your example but can't seem to get it right, i'm unable to use the getFilter() method on my

```
AppInfoAdapter adapter = new AppInfoAdapter(this, Utilities.getSystemFilteredApplication(this), getPackageManager());
```

The method 'getFilter()' is undefined for the type AppInfoAdapter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I have a ListView using a custom ArrayList adapter - what's the best way to implement filtering ? Anyone have a example code to study?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071368/i-have-a-listview-using-a-custom-arraylist-adapter-whats-the-best-way-to-impl)

Answer (score 0):

Definetely not the best code ever written, but you may have a look at my implementation that is working pretty well:

Line 252: https://github.com/iRail/BeTrains-for-Android/blob/master/src/tof/cv/mpp/StationPickerActivity.java

And this class: https://github.com/iRail/BeTrains-for-Android/blob/master/src/tof/cv/mpp/Utils/FilterTextWatcher.java

Comment: Tried to implement according to your example, but still can't get it working edited the code in the main post

Comment: You didn't tried according to my example ;-) see: search.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher); getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);

Comment: This is my current MainActivity.java, http://pastebin.com/BJWiWgcd but it is not working correctly still for some reasons.

Comment: Have you tried to debug, display logs or do you expect me to do it? Is the onTextChanged method called? are some values null? Should I guess?